# jQuery Waypoints: is Disable on all waypoints still possible?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I am about to include the jQuery Waypoints plugin (version 3 as the version 2 documentation is no longer available) in a new project. I will need to create 20+ waypoints for analytics events and enable/disable all of them in certain circumstances.

In the previous version of the API, I could simply do

```
 $.waypoints('disable');
```

and not worry about maintaining and going over a list of instances. Seems like the v.3 API will require this... am I missing something? Is it still possible to disable/enable all waypoints globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of Waypoints 3.1.0 the [enableAll](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/disable-all/) and [disableAll](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/disable-all/) methods have been added. The original answer below applied to 3.0.0 and 3.0.1

---

An analog to the old `$.waypoints('disable')` doesn't exist. There isn't a `Waypoint.disableAll()`. But you probably don't have to maintain your own list of Waypoint instances. You can use the Context's list:

```
Context.findByElement(window).waypoints.forEach(function(waypoint) {
  waypoint.disable()
})
```

If I see a bunch of people needing back global or Context scoped disable/enable I'd consider adding it back to v3.

Comment: Thank you, this addresses my use case. I may choose to maintain a list in case I'd like to disable some of the waypoints, like in the case of analytics events... would there be a more efficient way to do so?

Comment: When you create waypoints using `$(someSelector).waypoint(...)` in v3 it returns an array of Waypoint instances.

Comment: @aaandre I've added Waypoint.enableAll and disableAll to 3.1.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing support! I'll update my version asap.